# For Looping data in html and SketchUp

Tags: html, loops, sketchup

I have an array of data in SketchUp which I need to present to html in a table format. I have an example of my code which I have hard-coded.

```
ID = [["Harry", "22", "Male"],["Sam", "19", "Male"],["Christine", "23", "Female"]]

  dialog = UI::HtmlDialog.new(
    {
      :dialog_title => "Personal Info",
      :scrollable => true,
      :resizable => true,
      :width => 500,
      :height => 250,
      :left => 200,
      :top => 200,
      :min_width => 50,
      :min_height => 50,
      :max_width =>1000,
      :max_height => 500,
      :style => UI::HtmlDialog::STYLE_DIALOG
    })

for i in 0...Facelayers.length do
     html = "
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <style>
     table, th, td {
       border:1px solid black;
     }
     </style>
       <body>
         <h2>Personal Info</h2>
     <table style='width:75%'>
       <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
     <td>Age</td>
     <td>Gender</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
     <td>#{ID[0][0]}</td>
         <td>#{ID[0][1]}</td>
         <td>#{ID[0][2]}</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
     <td>#{ID[1][0]}</td>
         <td>#{ID[1][1]}</td>
         <td>#{ID[1][2]}</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
     <td>#{ID[2][0]}</td>
         <td>#{ID[2][1]}</td>
         <td>#{ID[2][2]}</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     </body>
     </html>
   "
   dialog.set_html(html)
   dialog.show 
   i=i+1
  end
```

If you run this program in SketchUp, you will have the following output...

[image]

The output is perfect, couldn't get any better. But the problem is that its hardcoded.

You'll notice that the 'ID' array has three people with different names, ages and genders. But what if I had four people? Or five? Or even ten?

This part here needs to somehow be looped. Could someone please help me with creating a loop which will print all the information necessary to html?

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Ruby Script

```rb
ids = [%w[Harry 22 Male], %w[Sam 19 Male], %w[Christine 23 Female], %w[Rafael 39 Male]]
@rows = ""

@dialog = UI::HtmlDialog.new(
  {
    dialog_title: 'Personal Info',
    scrollable: true,
    resizable: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 250,
    left: 200,
    top: 200,
    min_width: 50,
    min_height: 50,
    max_width: 1000,
    max_height: 500,
    style: UI::HtmlDialog::STYLE_DIALOG
  }
)

ids.each do |data|
  @rows.concat "<tr><td>#{data[0]}</td><td>#{data[1]}</td><td>#{data[2]}</td></tr>"
end

html = "
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <style>
      table, th, td {
      border:1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
    <body>
      <h2>Personal Info</h2>
      <table style='width:75%'>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Age</td>
          <td>Gender</td>
        </tr>
        #{@rows}
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
"

@dialog.set_html(html)
@dialog.show
```

##### Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to build HTML dialog.
It is much better to build a basic HTML page, and from HTML you could send request to ruby by using `sketchup.get_init_data()` with js to form the table.
The `get_init_data` is the method defined in ruby and registered to `add_action_callback` method.

The reason you should use such a patten is that if the table is getting complicated or you have many other tables, it will very difficult to organize the HTML string in ruby.